# Unique Tree using Inorder & Postorder traversals

Tags: data-structures, trees

This question appeared in my data structures examination :

You are given that GDCBFAHEJ is an in-order traversal and GCDBHJAEF is a post-order traversal.  Either build the unique tree for which these are traversals or argue that they are traversals of different trees.

Why are we unable to build a unique tree, despite of having a in-order & post-order traversal?
Please explain.

Comment: Look at the 2nd alternative: or *argue that they are traversals of different trees*.

Answer (score 0):

Given the in-order and the post-order, there is indeed a unique corresponding binary tree.

Since $F$ is the last node in the post-order, it is the root of the tree.

In the in-order, the root of the tree separates the in-order of the left tree (hence GDCB) and the in-order of the right tree (AHEJ).

That means that the left tree is of size 4. In the post-order, the first 4 nodes must represent the post-order of the left tree (GCDB). Similarly, the post-order of the right tree is HJAE.

Using the same method recursively, we get that the left tree is:

```
    B
   /
  D
 / \
G   C
```

But the problem is that when using the method on a tree with AHEJ as in-order and HJAE as post-order, we get that the root must be E, but then it decompose the in-order as AH (in-order of left tree), E (root) and J (in-order of right-tree).
Can you see how it is a contradiction with the post-order?